# Get Membership Users and Emails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I find it difficult to understand the structure of the MembershipUserCollection class. For example, I get All Users as a MembershipUserCollection, yet I cannot access MembershipUser to get the users emails. Here is a sample of what I currently do:

```
 MembershipUserCollection AllUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();
 foreach (var user in AllUsers)
   {
     var userName = user.ToString();
     // Is there a better way to get the email within loop without having to call the GetUser method??
     var email = Membership.GetUser(user).Email 
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
foreach (MembershipUser user in AllUsers)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Is there any technical term that describes what just happened? I mean var would return object while specifying the type is needed in order to get access to the inner class instance

Comment: well i suppose it's because the `MembershipUserCollection` is just a class inherits from the generic `ICollection, IEnumerable` and it's not a strongly typed `IEnumerable<MembershipUser>`

Comment: it allows you to store any object that inherits from `MembershipUser` also, so you might be using a `SpecialMemberShipUser : MembershipUser` and returning that in your `MembershipUserCollection` so it allows you to cast the objects as any `MembershipUser` object